# Wallet RPC (transfer): Empty Transaction Key (tx_key) received

Tags: rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

I run into an issue where when submitting an RPC request to the `transfer` method,
the `tx_key` (that helps prove a tx was made) is not being returned.

I explicitly mention `get_tx_key` so that the `tx_key` gets returned. According to the [`transfer` RPC documentation](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer).

Also made sure I set `store-tx-info` to `1` in the CLI.

Sample request:

```
array (
  'destinations' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'amount' => '0.01314010',
     'address' => '44P8rkTRW5u1i...cEePYi4J5Vr3QLimydCX',
  )),
  'mixin' => 4,
  'get_tx_hex' => true,
  'get_tx_key' => true,
  'payment_id' => 'xxxx...xxxx',
)
```

What is being returned is:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'amount' => 1140160000,
   'fee' => 10785600000,
   'multisig_txset' => '',
   'tx_blob' => '',
   'tx_hash' => 'xxxx...xxxx',
   'tx_key' => '',
   'tx_metadata' => '',
))
```

As you can see the `tx_key` property was returned empty. This isn't the desired nor correct behavior.
Any ideas?

Comment: While this does seem to be a bug, you probably want to use the transfer_split RPC instead, which is the one that's commonly used (and more tested).

Answer (score 1):

Tx keys are stored in the wallet you use to make a transaction.

Tx keys cannot, however, be recovered if you restore a wallet from seed. If you have multiple wallets, only the wallet that you used to make the transaction will have a record of the tx key for that transaction (unless you have manually exported and imported those tx keys to the additional wallet).